# Get return value of jar/class file from batch file of particular string

Tags: java, batch-file

```
class Demo
    {
        public static void main(String a[])
        {
           System.out.println("abc def");
           System.out.println("123 456");
           System.out.println("aaa bbb");
        }
    }
```

Batch File:

```
for /f "tokens=1-2" %%A in ( ' java Test ' ) do set token1=%%A token2=%%B
```

I am executing above class through batch file. My expectation is to get only second line and particularly "123" only. how to get it.

When I execute the batch file, it returns all values.

Comment: So you want to `Skip` the first line, retrieve the first `Token`, (`%%A`), then end the `For` loop!

Comment: yes. In my real scenario, I have lot of logs. but I need to get particular value. in this case i need only "123"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will do as you require:

```bat
@For /F Skip^=1 %%A In ('java Test 2^>Nul')Do @Set "Token=%%A"&GoTo :Next
:Next
@Set Token 2>Nul&Pause
```

Where the last line is included just to output the variable and value. *You would obviously change that as necessary*.

Comment: @Srinivasan, I have noted, that you had previously accepted this answer, but have since revoked it; can you please explain why?